# Tracking one face on camera?

Tags: c++, opencv, face-detection

This code is returning a lot of faces per frame. I want to obtain only one face per frame, is there any code or way to achieve this?

My code is:

```
CvSeq * detectRect_face; 
detectRect_face = cvHaarDetectObjects(frame, pCascade_face, storage,1.15, 3, 0,cvSize(100,100));

for(int i=0;i<(detectRect_face ? detectRect_face->total:0); i++ )
    {
        CvRect* r = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem(detectRect_face, i); 
        CvPoint pt1 = { r->x, r->y }; 
        CvPoint pt2 = { r->x + r->width, r->y + r->height }; 
        cvRectangle(frame, pt1, pt2, CV_RGB(255,0,0), 1,8, 0); 

    }
```

Comment: Doesn't removing the loop result in 1 result? Or do you want to be able to select a specific index?

Comment: You could pass `CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT` as the `flags` parameter to `cvHaarDetectObjects`. That would return at most one object (the biggest one).

Comment: Also, if you detect faces each frame, even if you restrict the result to one you cannot be sure that the face you are detecting in the current frame is the same face than the one in the previous frame. You should see topics like optical flow (Lucas-Kanade), Kalman filter, etc. to get true tracking of the face over a video stream.